# ¿Como cambio el color de las celdas al datagridview con formato condicional?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Quisiera saber la forma para lograr darle color a las celdas en mi `DataGridView` en C# usando el formato condicional para cuando tenga un empleado activo o inactivo

```
private void dgvempleados_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dgvempleados.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "estatus")
            {
                if (e.Value.ToString() == "inactivo")
                {
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;

                }
```

yo hago uso de este código pero a la hora de observar los colores me marca este error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida
>   como instancia de un objeto.'
>
> System.Windows.Forms.ConvertEventArgs.Value.get devolvió null.

Comment: a que te refieres con "observar los colores" ? o sea inicias y el codigo ejecuta pero si pasas el mouse o te posicionas en una celda genera el fallo

Comment: Si, es que la columna estatus la tengo de ultima ya que otras 9 columnas y estatus va de ultimo.

Comment: ehh no veo que tiene que ver que esa columna este al ultimo con el error que mencionas. Como creas esa columna? esta bindeada a los datos

Comment: Lo dije por si acaso ese sea el problema.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, tenía que poner AllowUserToAddRow en false. Pero igual gracias por tratar xD